# Which exceptions should a program never attempt to recover from?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Exceptions can have different degrees of impact on a program. For example a program should probably abort if `OutOfMemoryException` is raised, but it is possible to safely and appropriately handle `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` without putting the program in an unknown state.

I do understand that any exception has the potential to put the program in an unstable state if it is not properly handled. Are there exceptions that should never be handled beyond simply logging and throwing up the stack?

Comment: Every exception is eventually caught by _something_, even if it's the language runtime or the OS.

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers on this question. One provides the specific, techincal answer and the other provides the very import underlying principle.

Comment: AakashM did technically answer your specific question.  I'm still getting valid props from the community, so it's cool.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [Framework Design Guidelines cover this pretty completely](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229007.aspx):

> Do not catch System.Exception or System.SystemException in framework
>   code, unless you intend to re-throw.
>
> ...
>
> Do not catch System.StackOverflowException.
>
> It is extremely difficult to programmatically handle a stack overflow.
>   You should allow this exception to terminate the process and use
>   debugging to determine the source of the problem.
>
> ...
>
> Do not catch System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException explicitly.

Answer (score 36):

This is a case-by-case theoretical question, so the answer will be just as theoretical.  The best answer I've ever heard is, "**Don't handle an exception if you don't know *how* to handle it.**"  Logging a message and throwing the exception up the stack is fine because you've actually *done* something (even if it's just indicating that an error has occurred).  But, catching an error and *not* throwing it up the stack can result in hidden bugs and difficult debugging sessions.

What we've always done is implement a top-level error handler that will perform generic error handling (like log a message, alert the developers, etc.).  All exceptions that are unhandled deeper in the code are at least processed by the top-level handler.  The exceptions that *can be* handled lower in the code certainly are handled where they occur.

Consider the case of looping on a list of email addresses to send a message to a mailing list.  An exception could occur if one of the email addresses is not properly formatted, but we don't want a single email address to cause the rest of the processing to fail.  By handling the specific exception type that occurs, we can log it (or even mark the email address as invalid) and continue processing the rest of the list.

**Bottom Line**:  Whether or not you handle a given exception type really depends on whether or not your code knows what to do to recover when the exception type occurs.

Comment: I've heard the quote for about not handling exceptions you don't know what to do with.  That is *hands down* the best advice I've heard regarding exception handling.  If you don't mind the language barrier, the book *Exceptional C++* explains the guarantees (basic, strong, now-throw) we can give library consumers with the classes we design and how to recover program state.

Comment: @Christoper - The best part about the quote is that it's cross-language and cross-platform.  It doesn't matter what language you use.  If the language supports throwing and handling exceptions, you should still follow the same "don't handle unless you know how" approach.

Comment: This is a good motto for exceptions, but does not really answer the OPs question. It is not at all theoretical to list the Never Catch exceptions as defined in the framework.

Comment: @ach - I disagree. Even with the official Framework guidelines, there could be times when you know how to *and want to* handle some of the exceptions that would generally be included in a "do not handle" list.

Comment: @TLS That is certainly fair, there are exceptions to every rule, but knowing a guiding principle is certainly valid.

Comment: @ach And that's why I voted up on the answer that references the Framework Guidelines.  Technically, that one does answer the question directly.  :)

Answer (score 4):

This is probably a different scenario, but any exception that implies a programmer error: `NullReferenceException`, `IndexOutOfRangeException`, etc. It means you have a bug in your code and you should fix it rather than handle it.

Comment: There are rare cases when you might actually *want* to catch something like a `NullReferenceException` to handle it, and it does not mean that there is a bug in your code. I wrote some code like that just recently: a long line of chained property gets (don't say Demeter's law, this is how the data is exposed by the API so what I have to work with), each of which might return `null`. Instead of a gazillion intermediate variable assignments and null checks, I just wrapped it in a try-catch and handle any null reference appropriately. *In that particular case*, it works well and is clean enough.

Answer (score 3):

That's highly dependent on your application. Most applications should probably show an error message and die for `OutOfMemoryException`, but not all - an example is a program called SmartRAM (I think that's the name) that recovers RAM by trying to allocate more and more memory until it gets that exception - this causes Windows to drop all cache in RAM, giving you more free memory.

So it really depends on what you're doing. If you, as the expert on your application, feel like you can safely recover from the exception, then you should.

Answer (score 1):

Typical exception hierarchies have two main branches, *runtime* and *logic* errors. The former can appear at any time, and the program seldom has a sensible idea of how to recover, the latter is an error condition that needs to be anticipated and handled.

Java makes this distinction explicit with their implementation of [checked exceptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Checked_exceptions); it is an error if any exception is not either handled or declared as a potential exception exit from the method, however anything descended from `RuntimeException` is implicitly okay.

If your program is compartmentalized appropriately *and* the use case allows for it, you can catch certain runtime exceptions and shut down the compartment where the exception originated, but that is only useful in specialized cases.

While this is actively enforced only in Java, the concept can be applied here as well:

- Failure to parse input data is an exception that can be handled easily, as it is clear which state the program is in when the exception is thrown, so cleanup is easy (continue with next input).
- Recovering from an out-of-memory condition is harder because you may need to remove the output file if the error occured while writing -- otherwise you end up with partial data.
- If your program accessed invalid memory, you should not attempt to recover because you may have overwritten something else already (after all, your program apparently does not know where its data is), and there is no way to guarantee that it will work correctly anymore.

Comment: I think I have one of those special use cases. It involves processing data sets of text-based data files (~5 files in each set, each file has a different format). If something goes wrong on one set, I need to continue processing the other sets.

Comment: I've extended my answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where in the program the exception is occurring.

In general, it's best to handle the exceptions that your individual section of code wants/knows how to handle and let the rest bubble up to be handled elsewhere, or not at all.